# almost complex actions on $\mathbb{R}^{6}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

As far as I understand, there are many almost complex structures on the $6$-torus. A class $(a_{1},...,a_{15}) \in \mathbb{Z}^{15} = H^{2}(T,\mathbb{Z})$ is $c_{1}$ of an almost complex structure iff all $a_{i}$ are even, since the tangent bundle is trivial hence the second steifel whitney class vanishes.

My question is, pick a non-standard almost complex structure (i.e. $c_{1} \neq 0$). We can lift the almost complex structure to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$, which will be invariant by some action of $\mathbb{Z}^{6}$, is it possible to do this explicitly?

Edit: This question has now been answered at mathoverflow by Robert Bryant. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377163/almost-complex-mathbbz6-action.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what is special about dimension $6$, here?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: An orientable 6-manifold $M$ admits an almost complex structure with first Chern class $c$ if and only if $c \equiv w_2(M) \bmod 2$. This is not true in any other dimension.